# coloring in imagesc

Tags: matlab

Can the functions A, B, and C be different colors?

```
Z = A + B + C;
imagesc(Z)
colormap(gray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not if you add them like that, because that makes it only one function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the image processing toolbox, you can use [IMSHOW](http://www.mathworks.it/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/imshow.html) to display `A`,`B`, and `C` as red, green and blue, respectively:

```
Z = cat(3,A,B,C);
imshow(Z)
```

You may need to scale `A`,`B`, and `C` so that their values go from 0 to 1, though.